# What is the time complexity of the following algorithm

Tags: c#, c, time-complexity

**The Question**

I am having trouble finding the time complexity of the following algorithm:

```
void f2(int n) {
    int i;
    if (n == 1) {
        return;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        f2(n - 1);
    }
}
```

**My Problem**

The solution I came to is O(2^n) but the right answer is stated as O(n!) and I do not understand how that is possible and would be really grateful if somebody could explain it to me.

Comment: why tag both C# and C... it is for sure not both

Comment: The first recursion goes from n to 0, the first inner from n - 1 to 0, the second one from 2 -2 to 0 and so on. Thus it´s `n * (n - 1) * ... * 2`

Comment: How did you come to `O(2^n)`?  If anything, each call is `O(n)` that calls `O(n)` that calls `O(n)`that calls `O(n)`... for a net `O(pow(n,n))` - which is akin to  [`n!`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial)

Answer (score 2):

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        f2(n - 1);
    }
```

so outer loop runs n times, and recursively calls (n times) a inner loop which runs n-1 times, until you reach 1.

So it runs `n!` times all right.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below function

```
void fact(int n) {
   int i;
   if (n == 1) {
      return;
   }
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    fact(n-1);
  }
}
```

**Assume `n=2`;**

the function becomes

```
void fact(int n) {

    fact(1);
    fact(1);

}
```

Seems like time complexity is exponential.

**Now Assume `n=4`**

```
void fact(int n) {

    fact(3); 
    // -- this leads to fact(2) fact(2) fact(2) 
    // -- which leads to fact(1) fact(1) fact(1) fact(1) fact(1) fact1)

    fact(3);
    fact(3);
    fact(3);
}
```

ultimately it ends up with `O(n!)`